# Gunicorn error: Socket error processing request

Tags: python, plotly-dash, gunicorn

I have upgraded my Dash application to use gunicorn 21.1.0 (from 20.1.0) and I'm getting this unexpected error in the application log when submitting a request from the browser:

```
[2023-07-19 20:52:51 +1000] [56562] [ERROR] Socket error processing request.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/dade/.conda/envs/viz-davide/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/gthread.py", line 285, in handle
    keepalive = self.handle_request(req, conn)
  File "/Users/dade/.conda/envs/viz-davide/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/gthread.py", line 357, in handle_request
    util.reraise(*sys.exc_info())
  File "/Users/dade/.conda/envs/viz-davide/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gunicorn/util.py", line 641, in reraise
    raise value
  File "/Users/dade/.conda/envs/viz-davide/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/gthread.py", line 343, in handle_request
    resp.write(item)
  File "/Users/dade/.conda/envs/viz-davide/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gunicorn/http/wsgi.py", line 326, in write
    self.send_headers()
  File "/Users/dade/.conda/envs/viz-davide/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gunicorn/http/wsgi.py", line 322, in send_headers
    util.write(self.sock, util.to_bytestring(header_str, "latin-1"))
  File "/Users/dade/.conda/envs/viz-davide/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gunicorn/util.py", line 299, in write
    sock.sendall(data)
OSError: [Errno 9] Bad file descriptor
```

My application is configured to work with multiple processes. Is this a gunicorn bug or has my configuration broken some new assumptions?